# И, задув свечу, громко я захохочу — так(,) что стены замка задрожат!

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая? Я считпю, что именно тире нужно, так как *так(,) что стены задрожат* — прибавка к наречию *громко*, то бишь пояснение.

> Я за пять минут страх посею тут, превращу покои замка в ад. И, задув свечу, громко я захохочу — так(,) что стены замка задрожат!

P. S. Это песня боярсская про привидение.